Microsoft Teams: How can I forward all messages sent to an Incoming Webhook to a Group Chat?
Given:

I've configured an Incoming Webhook for a Microsoft Teams channel.
I can use POST calls to programmatically post messages to this channel.

Question:

I'd like to post these messages to a group chat. How can I do this?
Can I (or should I) use Power Automate to intercept the messages sent to the Incoming Webhook (or channel) and forward them as is to the group chat?



You have a screenshot showing a graphical/no-code interface on Power Automate with an error message about invalid parameters. Can you please provide information on the parameters you have tried to include which prompted the error? We need to see a [mcve] in order to help you with "code" (if there is any here) that does not work. If there's no code involved in this process you're trying to achieve, the question may be appropriate on web applications.SE, but would be off-topic here.

You can use Power Automate to automate the process of forwarding messages from the Incoming Webhook to the Group Chat.
Set up a flow in Power Automate that trigger when a message is received from the Incoming Webhook and then sends it to the Group Chat. Ref:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/custom-connectors/create-webhook-trigger#use-the-webhook-as-a-trigger

You should use Power Automate. Teams Connectors are being retired in the next few weeks: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/microsoft365dev/retirement-of-office-365-connectors-within-microsoft-teams/
Here is a working Webhook sent from PowerShell. My application only supports top level JSON keys, so I am using the "text" key:
$WebhookUri = "https://prod-157.westus.logic.azure.com:443/workflows/..."


$adaptiveCardJson = @"
{ "type": "messagecard",
  "text": "Test 9" ,}          
"@
Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST $WebhookUri -Body $adaptiveCardJson -ContentType 'application/json'

Here is the Power Automate flow. You would change the "Post in" to "Group Chat".
Power Automate Flow
